# PHP array two values and call a pair

Tags: php, arrays

I have something like this:

```
host1 | port1
host2 | port2
host3 | port3
host4 | port4
```

Now, I need to insert pairs into an array so I can use them in a loop:

I tried to loop through one value of an array

```
$hosts  = array('host1','host2','host3'); 

foreach ($hosts as $host) {

   echo $host;

}
```

How do I add pairs to an array so I can call say `host` it outputs both host and port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your array like this which creates named keys for each host:

```
$hosts = array(
    'host1' => 'port1',
    'host2' => 'port2',
    'host3' => 'port3'
);
```

(Example #1 here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php)

You can then iterate through the array like so to grab the array key and value:

```
foreach($hosts as $host => $port){
    echo 'This is the ' . $host;
    echo 'This is the ' . $port;
}
```

(http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: A small add to that, how can i do the same with three values in an array?

Comment: You can combine my answer with @Bill's and construct your array like this:

`$hosts = array('host1' => array('port1a', 'port1b'));`

You can then access the data in that array like so:

`echo $hosts['host1'][0]; // Will echo 'port1a'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use multidimensional array. Like this

```
$data= array
  (
  array("host1","yourport1"),
  array("host2","yourport2"),
  array("host3","yourport3"),
  );
```

and can access like this

```
echo "Host: ". $data[0][0]." Port: ".$data[0][1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add arrays to the array, so you get an multidimensional array:

```
$hosts = array(array('host1', 'port1'), array('host2', 'port2'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Fast way:

```
// also You can define it as string directly, but I think You have a file :)
foreach(explode(PHP_EOL,file_get_contents('myIP.txt')) as $line){
     $hosts[explode(' | ',$line)[0]] = explode(' | ',$line)[1];
}

var_dump($hosts); 

// You will have pairs host1 => port1, host2=>port2, etc
```

There's on more way with `array_walk`, but I'm too lazy to read docs about `array_walk`. Hope this solution will completly solve Your task

Comment: No, the data i need to add to an array is static, it never changes, something like config part of a PHP project to import later to other scripts...but thanks anyway for your answer

Comment: @skymario84 so You can define var like `$myhosts = "host1 | port1 \r\n host2 | port2 \r\n";` and replace `file_get_contents('myIP.txt')` with `$myhosts`. It'll work. Cheers